# How to declare AlertDialog.Builder outside OnCreate method of the activity I want to use it in?(Xamarin.Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog

I want to declare `AlertDialog.Builder` outside OnCreate method of the activity class I want to use it in. If I wanted to use it in the activity I declare it in  it's easy I just put in OnCreate method:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

But if I want it to be outside OnCreate method or the activity class I want to use it but in the same namespace or if I want it to be in another namespase or in another activity what do I have to put in the place of `this` keyword?

Answer (score 0):

> How to declare AlertDialog.Builder outside OnCreate method of the activity I want to use it in?(Xamarin.Android)

It needs a `Context` as its construction parameters, so give your `AlertDialog` a `Context` will solve this problem.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context);
```

Furthermore, you could refer to: [What is 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-on-android)